# How to check, whether the records are exist into a table in SQLite database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm query following onto a table to check whether it's populated with records or not.

```
NSString *selectSQL = @"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tableName LIMIT 1)";
const char *selectSQLConstant = [selectSQL UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, selectSQLConstant, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        //even if the table is empty, condition is always true.
    }
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Is this the correct way or something still I needs to add?

**Update:**

I ended up by changing my query,

```
NSString *selectSQL = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName LIMIT 1";
```

but there's still a *?* for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString *selectSQL = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName LIMIT 1";`

checks wether there is at least 1 entry in the table... if thats what you want, this is fine

Answer (score 1):

Use this method :

```
-(BOOL)recordExistOrNot:(NSString *)query{
    BOOL recordExist=NO;
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                recordExist=YES;
            }
            else
            {
                //////NSLog(@"%s,",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
    }
    return recordExist;
}
```

It will return YES if record exists else not. Ex :

```
NSString *query  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from yourtable where column_name = 'column_name'"];

        NSLog(@"query : %@",query);
        BOOL recordExist = [self recordExistOrNot:query];

        if (!recordExist) {
            // Insert your data
        }
```

Hope it helps you.